# Python3 Attribute Error int object has no attribute

Tags: python-3.x, attributeerror

Hi I am getting an attribute error on my code and as I am only a beginner programmer I am unsure where I have gone wrong.

```
import sys

class BankAccount(object):

   def __init__(self, balance = 0):
      self.balance = balance

   def withdraw(self, other):
      if other.balance <= self.balance and self.balance > 0:
         self.balance = self.balance - other.balance
      else:
         return('Insufucient funds available')

   def deposit(self, other):
      if self.balance > 0:
         self.balance = self.balance + other.balance

   def __str__(self):
      return('Your current balance is: {0:.2f} euro'.format(self.balance))
```

It keeps saying `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'balance'`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you use your `BankAccount`?

Comment: deposit() : adds an amount (supplied as an argument) to the balance
withdraw() : subtracts an amount (supplied as an argument) from the balance (or says ‘Insufficient funds available’ if withdrawing that amount would cause the balance to become negative)

Comment: I wonder if that amount is an `int` rather than `BankAccount` instance.

Comment: what do you mean by this? So sorry, I am only learning.

Answer (score 0):

Change `b1.withdraw(1)` to `b1.withdraw(BankAccount(1))` and all things alike.

Param `other` should be a `BankAccount` instance which has a `balance` attribute, rather than an `int`.